# PHP rtrim and ltrim are trimming more than supposed to

Tags: php

Im wanting to remove the `Search -` from a page on my website. Here is an example of my code below:

**Input:**

```
$search = "Search - echelon";
$trim = "Search - ";

$result = ltrim($search,$trim);


echo $result;
```

**The Output:**

`lon`

**Desire Output:**

`echelon`

How can I do this, and why does ltrim trim off more in my example above? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RTM](http://php.net/ltrim). The second argument is treated as a set of characters to trim.

In this case:

```
S - in the list, trim it
e - in the list, trim it
a - in the list, trim it
r - in the list, trim it
c - in the list, trim it
h - in the list, trim it
_ - (space) in the list, trim it
- - in the list, trim it
_ - (space) in the list, trim it
e - in the list, trim it
c - in the list, trim it
h - in the list, trim it
e - in the list, trim it
l - NOT in the list, stop!

lon is left
```

Did you mean this?

```
$result = substr($search,strlen($trim));
```

Comment: Note that `substr` removes the first letters of the string regardless of what they are; i.e. even if the string doesn't start with "Search - ", it'll still cut off the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

`ltrim ( string $str [, string $character_mask ] )` - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string.  character_mask - characters you want to strip

How about `str_replace`,

```
$result = str_replace($trim,"",$search);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late. But all excuses aside.
I have found PHP trim to remove too much quite often. That much that I found it unreliable to use. It simply is a PHP bug that has gone by unattended.

Hence therefore I am using :

```
function phptrim($str, $strip = ' '){
    while($str != '' && substr($str, 0, 1) == $strip)  $str = substr_replace($str, '', 0, 1);
    while($str != '' && substr($str, -1) == $strip)    $str = substr_replace($str, '', -1);

    return $str;
}
```

Note that this is a little CPU intensive if you are using this in a loop. So try to avoid needing it. But if you need it. Here it is.

Comment: So it works with $strip string of more than one character:  while($str != '' && substr($str, 0, strlen($strip)) == $strip)  $str = substr_replace($str, '', 0, strlen($strip));

Answer (score 1):

[from PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php): ltrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string

So it doesn't trim the string, it trims any of the characters you entered...

I would go with @krishR's answer

Answer (score 1):

`trim` trims off *any of the characters* that you give it. It looks at each character individually and trims it off, it doesn't search for the string as a whole. If you're looking to *remove a string from the start if and only if it exist*, do this:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('/^Search - /', '', $search);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
// Example 
$ageTypes = ' Adult, Child, Kids, ';
// Output, removes empty string from both ends 
// Adult, Child, Kids,

// Rtrim  - Remove characters from the right side of a string: 
// Example 
$ageTypes = 'Adult, Child, Kids';
echo rtrim($ageTypes, ',');
// Output 

// Ltrim - Remove characters from the left side of a string: 
// Example 
$ageTypes = ',Adult, Child, Kids, ';
echo ltrim($ageTypes, ',');
// Adult, Child, Kids,
```