# PHP string function chop() does not give desired output

Tags: php, string, function

The following code:

```
<?php
    $str='Who are you?';
    echo chop($str,'you?').'<br>';
    echo chop($str,'are you?').'<br>';
?>
```

gives me the output:

```
Who are
Wh
```

Why the second output is

```
Wh
```

and not

```
who
```

Comment: I think you should use `substr()` instead of `chop` based upon your requirement to split string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP rtrim and ltrim are trimming more than supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089101/php-rtrim-and-ltrim-are-trimming-more-than-supposed-to)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because:

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   `chop` — Alias of `rtrim()`

and

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   `rtrim` — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string
>
> `string rtrim ( string $str [, string $character_mask ] )`

So... you're feeding a character mask.

Given that, "o" is in that mask, so it gets trimmed out

Comment: Then why in the first output 'o' is not trimmed and the result is 'Who are'

Comment: Because `rtrim` only removes the ending characters. The ones on the right side, if they match the mask. This isn't `str_replace`.

Answer (score 2):

In your string you have specified a `character_mask`, this is what reference says:

> **character_mask**:
>   You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

In your case, there's an 'o' in the mask, for this reason all 'o' in `$str` have been deleted.